# Use mapped network drive with FileUpload control

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5

My ASP.NET 3.5 application is installed on server 1. In this server I have a mapped network drive Q:

When I try to use SaveAs of File Upload control, I am hard coding the path as:

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs("Q:\MyFiles\") & FileUpload1.FileName)
```

It gives error: Path not found.

How to put network drive path with SaveAs?

Comment: The problem is, *you* have mapped the drive, but the user account the site runs on hasn't. You have to use UNC paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drive mappings are per user, so the user the site runs on has no idea of your mappings. The best way to fix this is to use UNC paths instead, so there is no need for drive mappings.

So if you map server `X`'s share `Share` to Q, just instead save to `\\X\Share\`+whatever

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs("\\X\Share\MyFiles\") & FileUpload1.FileName)
```